# Error specifying js file path in template html file in Single page application using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Getting an error while adding the js file path in the template url html file, instead of adding it to index.html file

https://github.com/souravsaha1605/angularjs-ui_router

'master' branch is updated with the javascript file nested_one/chennai.js in index.html file

'js_path_in_template' branch is updated with the javascript file nested_one/chennai.js inside nested_one/chennai.html file, which is triggering an error

```
angular.js:14800 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'Chennai' is not registered.
```

Please help in either mentioning how to solve the issue or making a pull request to the repository

Also suggesting a better solution or updating in the repository to specify multiple js, css files and controller / sub controller names inside appRoute.js for specific template url would be really helpful

**Note**: Please read the README file for running the project in your local machine

Answer (score 1):

It will not work when you nest it inside of the template file because the chennai.js file will not be loaded until the template is loaded and Angular will look for that controller when the route is being loaded.

If you want to load it in the template than you need to look into lazy loading the module. UI-Router provides a guide in their documentation: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/lazyloading#angularjs